# Windows 2008 R2 vpn tunnel to DD-WRT

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2008-r2, openvpn, ipsec, router

I've DD-WRT router in one location with all servers (Windows 2008 R2) and workstations. In hosting I have Windows 2008 R2 Server with public IP address.

I need to setup permanent VPN connection so that I can safely access Hosting server from my client's office without needing to setup any additional vpn connections. 
The best bet for me was to setup perm IPSEC connection between DD-WRT and Windows in location.

Anyone did something like this before? Got any hints/steps for setting up Routing and Remote Access and DD-WRT correctly for this vpn tunnel?

Comment: Why not OpenVPN again? It'd be a breeze making your Windows boxen connect to DD-WRT running openvpn server, just follow the HOWTO on their website.

Comment: I have OpenVPN installed on DD-WRT and on workstations that connect using vpn. I guess I could make Windows in hosting use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(converting comment to answer)

Why not OpenVPN again? It'd be a breeze making your Windows boxen connect to DD-WRT running openvpn server, just follow the HOWTO on their website.

Comment: It works nicely :-) OpenVPN as service so starts/stop nicely.